# Rails 3.1 - rails not resolving (windows)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows

I setup rails 3.1.0.rc5 on my friends vista machine last week. Everything installed and i can run an application we're working on just fine, however, the rails command does not resolve. To start the server, i had to do the old fashioned: ruby script/rails s style. He has the ruby bin on his path, as ruby -v resolves fine. Any ideas on what to check?

Note i downloaded a 1.9.2 installer from rubyinstaller.org, setup the dev pack, and installed rails through bundler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your path isn't pointing to your rails gem bin.

My first suggestion was going to be use `rvm` but since you're on windows that won't be an option.  RVM suggested [pik](https://github.com/vertiginous/pik) for windows users, and if it works similar to RVM, you'll save yourself a ton of headaches.

Comment: This seemed to be the problem, even though i already tried it. It looks like the C:\Ruby192\bin needed to be added to the Path system variable as well. After that, I reinstalled the rails gem on my friends computer, and it worked.

Comment: I has having a similar resolution problem, and also want to make note that order matters in a Windows path. I have both 1.9.3 and 1.9.2 installed, and had to make sure that the path to 1.9.3 was listed first.